# Symfony2 Sonata Project - SonataTimelineBundle Issue

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using sonatatimeline bundle in my project. As per docs given by sonatatimeline bundle 
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/timeline/master/doc/reference/installation.html .

I had followed the steps and it was successfully configured.

I am facing a problem when I create or update anything, it shows **actions.sonata.admin.create or actions.sonata.admin.update** in timeline block  instead of **admin has created hello** or **admin has updated hello**.

[image]

I have no clue what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. I had pulled the old  repository of sonata timeline bundle. I change my composer.json with the new version of sonata timeline bundle  and updated. My problem got fixed.

Happy